# How can I use Hibernate Template object for persisting multiple transient objects in one transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to store two transient/ POJO objects in to the database using Hibernate Template. For example there are two objects Employee and Address. Obviously I need to store first Employee then Address, if storing Employee object cause any problem then the Address object must not be stored. I can do this using raw coding like getting session, begin a transaction, persist the two objects then commit the transaction.
I want to perform this similar behavior using Hibernate Template.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same like you have mentioned. here is the flow

```
session.beginTransaction();

employeeHybernateTemplateDao.save(employee);  // this will run under the transaction boundaries declared above

addressHybernateTemplateDao.save(address);    // this will run under the transaction boundaries declared above

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

`employeeHybernateTemplateDao` would be the DAO that you create implementing the hybernatetemplate functionality in `save` method like below

```
HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

public void save(Employee employee){
     template.save(employee);        

}
```

Comment: Thank you Zeus, nice Idea, why I didn't get this in my head ;-)